# how to show dialog from my application for result (like google play game)

Tags: android, dialog, google-play, google-play-games

i don't know the word to find the document!
i need to create dialog just like google play game for choosing email account or in-app billing dialog so other apps can access it.
BTW i need to show it from remote service

Update:
I need to implement it in my application, so other applications use startactivityforresult, my app shows dialog.
To be more pacific for example: 
My app is google play game
Other apps try login with gmail and get dialog to choose email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this, this may help you
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your full requirement, but i can suggest some steps. in your service you can make a handler and then you can show dialog using that handler on a activity of your choice. you can override onActivityResult() to handle the call back. in your activity. it would be great if you post your code for insights.

Hope it helps :)